# Display only certain percentages

Tags: gtsummary

I have chosen the percentage calculation by rows. What do I have to do to get only the percentage displayed for certain columns?
Thanks in advance!

```
  Table1234 %>% 
    select(everything(), -c(screening_id, m07_mainsourceincome_c, m01_2_ageyears_q, r_sample)) %>% 
    tbl_summary(by = "test_result", 
                percent = "row",
                digits = NULL,
                label = list(age_group_10yrs ~ "Age Groups", 
                             m01_1_sex_d ~ "Sex",
                             m05_qualificationmg_c ~ "Education", 
                             m06_indivemployment_c ~ "Profession",
                             m06_indivemployment_currently_employed ~ "Employment Status")) %>% 
    modify_column_hide(., columns = stat_1) %>% 
  bold_labels() %>% 
    add_p() %>% 
   add_overall()
```

Comment: it would be helpful to provide a sample of your data, but using the `statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}%"` might be what you are looking for

Comment: and expected output would also be helpful